# Not Displaying Array Lines

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table

I currently have a problem.

I have setup a TeamSpeak script that displays the ban list in PHP.

It displays them on a table through foreach. 
But I don't want it to display bans that don't have a UID.

This is the script:

```
<table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Unique Ban ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>UID</th>
                    <th>Created</th>
                    <th>Duraction</th>
                    <th>Invoker</th>
                    <th>Reason</th>
                </tr>
                <? foreach ($banlist['data'] as $row) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <? if($banid == ""){ $banid = "Not Yet Assigned"; } echo $banid; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <? echo $row['lastnickname']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <? echo $row['uid']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <? echo $row['created']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <? if($row['duration'] == '0' ){ $row['duration'] = "Permanent"; } else { $row['duration'] = gmdate("H:i:s", $row['duration']); } echo $row['duration']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <? echo $row['invokername']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <? echo $row['reason']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <? endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

It currently shows bans that don't how a UID/`$row['uid']`
How do I stop `foreach` displaying whole lines that don't have a UID.

The Array format is like this:

```
Array ( [success] => 1 [errors] => Array ( ) [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [banid] => 22 [ip] => [name] => [uid] => {uid} [lastnickname] => {nickname} [created] => 1406227162 [duration] => 0 [invokername] => {name} [invokercldbid] => 30 [invokeruid] => {invokerid} [reason] => {reason} [enforcements] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [banid] => 23 [ip] => 0.0.0.0 [name] => [uid] => [lastnickname] => [created] => 1406227162 [duration] => 0 [invokername] => {name} [invokercldbid] => 30 [invokeruid] => {uid} [reason] => {reason} [enforcements] => 0 ) ) )
```

I blanked some of them out for obvious reasons, so all places I blanked out start and end with `{}`.

But in this case I don't want it to display the`Array[1]` because it contains only an IP and not the UID. How would I stop it from displaying the entire `Array[1]`?

Comment: Be carefull of the short open tag (`<?` instead of `<?php`) as it isn't enabled on all servers (not sure if that matters to you).

Comment: Oh thankies :D I didn't even realise I had the short tag. Changed it in my code. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<? foreach ($banlist['data'] as $row) : ?>
  <? if (empty($row['uid'])) continue; ?>
  ...
  [rest of foreach code]
  ...
<? endforeach; ?>
```

It will skip that cycle and go to the next item in the array.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @PetervanderWal I was thinking the same. Personally, I don't like breaking loops, but thought that in this case it was an acceptable trade-off. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a million for your help.